# JUnit tearDown implementation for Spring-test's SimpleNamingContextBuilder/DataSource

Tags: junit, tdd

I'm using this code snippet to mock JDBC Datasources from within Junit4:

```java
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        try {
            SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
            BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
            ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            ds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://address:port/db");
            ds.setUsername("user");
            ds.setPassword("pass");
            builder.bind("jdbc/db", ds);

            builder.activate();

            System.out.println("connected");
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            System.err.println("error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Specific imports:

```java
    import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
    import org.springframework.mock.jndi.SimpleNamingContextBuilder;
```

**Question**: how should I close the DataSource connections in a tearDown method?

The problem is that neither `builder` nor `ds` are class variables which could be referenced, perhaps should I just move `ds` to a class scope and then use it to close it's `Connection` objects?

Should I also "de-bind" the `DataSource` from the `NamingContext` or, that part doesn't really matter at all?

Comment: While this is on topic for this forum, you may get a faster response from https://StackOverflow.com